# Array match only one result

Tags: php, arrays, match

Is it possible to achive this?

i have some arrays

```
Array
(
    [1] => Model_Like Object
        (
            [_is_new:protected] => 
            [_frozen:protected] => 
            [_data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [user_id] => 5
                    [liked_by] => 1
                )

            [_custom_data:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_original:protected] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [user_id] => 5
                    [liked_by] => 1
                )

            [_data_relations:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_original_relations:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_reset_relations:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_view:protected] => 
            [_iterable:protected] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [2] => Model_Like Object
        (
            [_is_new:protected] => 
            [_frozen:protected] => 
            [_data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [user_id] => 5
                    [liked_by] => 2
                )

            [_custom_data:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_original:protected] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [user_id] => 5
                    [liked_by] => 2
                )

            [_data_relations:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_original_relations:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_reset_relations:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_view:protected] => 
            [_iterable:protected] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [4] => Model_Like Object
        (
            [_is_new:protected] => 
            [_frozen:protected] => 
            [_data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [user_id] => 5
                    [liked_by] => 6
                )

            [_custom_data:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_original:protected] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [user_id] => 5
                    [liked_by] => 6
                )

            [_data_relations:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_original_relations:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_reset_relations:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_view:protected] => 
            [_iterable:protected] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

And i only want tho show one matching result.

```
<?php foreach ($user->likes as $likes): ?>
<?php if($likes['liked_by'] == $logged_in_user_id): ?>
     <?php echo "you like it" ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php echo "you dont like it" ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

and this way i get the following results

```
you like it  you dont like it    you dont like it
```

Is there away to only show the matchig result?

Comment: You're sure you want to use the php tags that way (`<?php` & `?>`)? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `return;` that jumps out from the loop

```
<?php 
   $result = "you dont like it";
   foreach ($user->likes as $likes) {
     if($likes['liked_by'] == $logged_in_user_id) {
       $result = "you like it";
     }
   }
   echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: strange, if i do this, if it has a like it breaks the whole page nothing of the page content shows up just the you like it, and if there is no match the content is ok but not showing the echo "you dont like it" string

Comment: and what do you want? just one result? like it/dont like it?

Comment: would like both, like it and dont like it

Comment: okay didnt solved my problem, still the same not it doesnt show any string and the content disapears, gonna give you an upvote for your help and thanks, i think i will just give up, thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could jump out of the loop when you hit a match.  There are a variety of ways to accomplish this, from using a flag variable to breaking the flow of control on a match.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can filter the likes array to contain only the likes of the user. After that, you just take the first entry of that array, which is the first "like". To give you an impression:

```
$likesOfUser = array_filter($user->likes, function($c) use ($logged_in_user_id)
{
    return $c['liked_by'] == $logged_in_user_id;
});

$like = array_shift($likesOfUser);
```

But this is maybe somewhat over the top and only recommended, if you need the likes anyway in a seperate array.